# How to use the return value from one function in another in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use the return value from one function in another?

The code is something like this:

```
double process () {
       
     //doing something

       return result;
}

double calculation () {

       double sum = 0;
       sum = result + 10; //Want to use the result from the previous function here
   
       return sum;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `sum = process() + 10;`?

Comment: The prototype `double process()` means that the expression `process()` is a value of type `double`. You can use it in the same way that you use any other expression of that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options - you could store the return value in a variable and then use that variable, or you can use the function call directly.

Store in a variable like this -

```
double sum = 0, result = process();
sum = result + 10;
```

or use the call directly like this -

```
double sum = 0;
sum = process() + 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can directly call the function:

```
double calculation () {

       double sum = 0;

       sum = process(//something) + 10; 

       return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to call `process` inside `calculation` then you can do something like the below:

```
double process() {

    // doing something

    return result;
}

double calculation ( const double result ) {

    double sum = 0;
    sum = result + 10;

    return sum;
}


int main( )
{
    double sum = calculation ( process( ) ); // pass the output of process to
                                             // calculation as an argument
}
```